# Apple Watch base localisation shows wrong default language

Tags: localization, xcode8, apple-watch

I have an app localised in three languages (Simplified Chinese, French and Czech) with English as the development language.

[image]

While the localisations work perfectly on the iPhone, there is an issue with the Apple Watch: If a user has set the Watch language in any other language than English/French/Chinese/Czech, then the content is shown in Chinese instead of English (that should be the default).

According to this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1828/_index.html):

> If none of the user’s preferred languages are supported by your app, iOS chooses the language matching your app's development region (`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`).
>
> **Note:** Be sure to set `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` for your app. If you adopt Base Localization, make sure that the value of
>   `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` matches the language used by your content in
>   the `Base.lproj` folder.

I have confirmed both the above requirements are being satisfied  (`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion="en"` and all `Base.lproj` files are indeed in English). Is there something I'm missing? Again, this happens only for the Watch app and not for the iPhone one.

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430 , CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is the language and region, e.g. en-US, not just en.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not make any difference; the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I have both Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese but it choose Traditional Chinese as the default language. When I delete the Traditional Chinese translation English is selected.

I also set the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to en which is the default.

From your screen shot I didn't see English - Development English.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and found the solution in this thread: 
   https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86889

Basically, the watch extension needs needed a Localizable.strings (Base) file. Ordinarily on the iOS side you don't actually need to specify a Base version of the file, only the translations. But on the watch it seems to requires a base version of the file for the system to work at all there. In fact, I only had an Interface translated (in the watch app) and didn't even have a Localizable.strings in the watch extension... so I had to add some localizable strings in the extension, export translations, import them again, and then manually add a Base version (by checking Base in the Localization section of the File Inspector) because this apparently required thing isn't created automatically.