# Apple Watch uses localization language as base language

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have added Chinese (Simplified) localization to my app, while English is set as Development language. Both iOS app and Watch App, as well as Watch Extension have necessary localization files set up:

[image]

**iOS:**

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

**Watch App:**

[image]
[image]

**Watch Extension:**

[image]
[image]

All three `Info.plist` files have

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en_US</string>
```

as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646525/apple-watch-base-localisation-shows-wrong-default-language).

When I run the app on iPhone, everything works well in both English and Chinese system languages. Also, if I set a third language for system (e.g. Russian), iOS app gracefully falls back to base English (suggesting it's closest in preferred languages list).

Watch app also works ok in cases when Watch language is set either to English or Chinese. But should I set third language for the Watch - it falls back to Chinese, not English.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Localizable.strings (Base) file in Watch Extention. Please check the forum post.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86889

Comment: In this way we have DUPLICATION of resources between Watch bundle and Watch Extension bundle. First one (Watch) - storyboard localization itself; second one - "Localizable.strings" (crutch) inside the Watch Extension.